# mapbox : how can I use add a static prefix (or suffix) to an expression?

Tags: expression, mapbox

I would like to use mapbox expression to get an icon name.

But I need to add a prefix to the valus, because my icons are named **icon-0, icon-1, icon-2**...
while the values I get with the expression are just numbers, like **0,1,2,3**...

So my actual expression is

```
'icon-image': ['get', 'icon_id'],
```

which give me for instance **3**.  I need to have **icon-3**.

Is this possible ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out:

```
'icon-image': ['concat','icon-',['get', 'icon_id']]
```